# Rudimentary topology question: interior of a subset of a space is the union of all open sets contained in it.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm reviewing topology and just wanted to confirm that I am doing this correctly. Professor Janich has urged the readers of his classic text on topology to prove the following:

*Suppose $(X, \mathcal{O})$ is a topological space and $B \subset X$. Define the interior of the set $B$ as $\hat B$.*

Claim: The interior of $B,$ namely $\hat B$, is the union of all open sets contained in $B$.

Proof of $\Longrightarrow$: Let $ x\in \hat B$. Then by definition, $B$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Thus $\exists A \subset B $ such that $A$ is open and $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$ and $A \subset B$, it must be the case that  $x \in \bigcup\{\text{all open sets contained in $B$}\}$.

Proof of $\Longleftarrow$: Suppose $x \in \bigcup\{\text{all open sets contained in $B$}\}$. Just pick any one of them and call it, say, $A$. (Question: did I just use the axiom of choice?) $x \in A \subset B$ and $A$ is open, so $B$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and thus, $x$ is an interior point of $B$.

Is all of that correct? Please feel free to offer any corrections, thank you.

Comment: I prefer single arrows for implications, but you can get the double left arrow with `\Leftarrow` ($\Leftarrow$). If you want a long one, make it `\Longleftarrow`.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I find it irritating that in Latex we have \to and \gcd but not \from nor \lcm.

Comment: Don't use `\implies`, that adds unwanted spaces. There is `\impliedby` for the reverse arrow, but it has the same problem. `\Rightarrow` and `\Leftarrow` or `\Longrightarrow` and `\Longleftarrow` are better here. Personally I'd use the short versions.

Comment: You don't say what definition of interior you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $x$ and $y$ are sets, $$x \in \textstyle\bigcup y \iff (\exists z \in y) \ x \in z.$$

So, if $x$ is in the union of all the open sets contained in $B$, by definition of  union there exists an open set $A$ contained in $B$ such that $x \in A$. There is no need of choice here. By the way, write `\Longleftarrow` to obtain $\Longleftarrow$.

Comment: That makes sense. So then are you saying that my proof is correct, just a bit long-winded? Or did I phrase it incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly fine :) It should only be noted that there is no need for the axiom of choice, since everything follows from the definitions. Also, look at [this](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)!

Comment: That detexify app is awesome, wish I had that sooner!